# Darknet YOLO transfer learning and keep old classes

Tags: python, opencv, darknet

I'm using OpenCV following [this sample](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/8c25a8eb7b10fb50cda323ee6bec68aa1a9ce43c/samples/dnn/object_detection.py), with yolov3.weights yolov3.cfg and coco.names from Darknet repo as input. It's working fine but I need some additional class so I want to continue training from the yolov3.weights. I've found some similar answers but none of them solve my doubt. If I follow [this guide](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects) of AlexeyAB, then my obj.names will look like this.

```
my class
another class
```

What will be the output class ID of my classes? It'll be 0, 1 or 80, 81? How can I input it to OpenCV so still be able to recognize objects from COCO dataset classes and also my classes?

Comment: when you continue, you use the same cfg file that was provided with the pretrained network? Then you will have 80 classes, but sll clssses that you didnt train will probably be useless after your training.

Comment: @Micka I modify the cfg file according to AlexeyAB guide. I want to keep those classes, what should I do, is there any guide or similar work that I can follow?

Comment: use the original training data (coco) as well as your new data. You will not keep the same results for the pretrained classes, but if you train correctly, you should still get good results (can't be told, whether it will be better or worse). If you need the original results for 80 classes + your class, you'll have to split the network after frozen feature layers and train the detection layers for your class, but this isn't supported by the darknet framework directly, afaik, and it would introduce more processing time/ressources because you would have 2 times the number of detection layers.